# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when calling createClob() with Oracle internal JDBC driver

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I have a Java program loaded inside Oracle 11.2.0.3 database. I'm using Oracle's [Server-Side Internal Driver](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/ssid.htm#JJDBC28250) to communicate with the host database.

The problem is that when I'm trying to insert data into clob column

```
Clob clob = targetCon.createClob();
clob.setString(1, (String) value);
insertStm.setClob(col, clob);
```

I get an error

```
Exception in thread "Root Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
```

The same code works if I'm calling it from a standalone program (running outside the database). The driver information shows `Oracle JDBC driver version:11.2.0.3.0` in both cases.

I also tried the following code

```
String s = (String) value;
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(s);
insertStm.setCharacterStream(col, stringReader , s.length());
```

But this gave me

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested
```

[Doc ID 1484721.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1484721.1) in My Oracle Support instructed to use setClob()...

Why is my code working when running as a standalone program but throwing an error when using the internal driver (which has the same version)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be solved by wrapping the insert inside PL/SQL block

```
BEGIN
 INSERT id, c INTO clob_tab VALUES(?,?);
END;
```

and using setCharacterStream, but I'm still curious why the original code throws NoSuchMethodError